# EC.presence_of_element_located Using a variable for the value

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following line of code in my program which works fine:

```
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, 'Group_Documents_139')
```

I need to change the searched string to use a variable. I tried the following:

```
uploadsStartString2 = 'Group_Documents_139'
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, '{0}' .format(uploadsStartString2))
```

It does not work for some reason. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the variable you need to use the proper format of [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) and you can use either of the following approaches:

- Replacing the variable directly:

  ```
  uploadsStartString2 = 'Group_Documents_139'
  element_present = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, uploadsStartString2)))
  ```
- Using *`%s`*:

  ```
  uploadsStartString2 = 'Group_Documents_139'
  element_present = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "'%s'"% str(uploadsStartString2))))
  ```
- Using *`format()`*:

  ```
  uploadsStartString2 = 'Group_Documents_139'
  element_present = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "'{}'".format(str(uploadsStartString2)))))
  ```
- Using [*f-strings*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/):

  ```
  element_present = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, f"{uploadsStartString2}")))
  ```